# Creating a PDF from HTML Elements using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

I have been a frequent user of stack overflow for a long time but just never needed to create an account...until today.

I've hit a brick wall with my coding. My current project in my job is to create a table planner or seating planner of some sort with functionality to print the table plan (save as pdf).

My HTML elements on the page are dynamically generated by jquery and they are all appended to a container called "table-planner-container" or $("#table-planner-container"). These tables are basically div elements that are shaped to be round or rectangle tables with seats around that allows names to be dropped into the seats.

At any one time, I want the user to be able to save this table plan but converting the HTML contents of $("#table-planner-container") to pdf. I've tried using DOMPDF but seems you can't pass specific HTML contents into the method. It should basically be a snapshot of what the position and css of the tables are in the browser, straight to PDF.

Any ideas/tips would be much appreciated.

We use Symfony 1.4 for our project so it follows MVC style

Here is the HTML code on the page (indexSucess.php):

```
    <div id="table-planner-container">
     <!-- jQuery appends div elements here -->
    </div>
```

tableplan.js:

```
    function Add_Table(){
    var tableContainer = $("<div id=\"table" + numTables + "\" tabletype=\" + tableType + "\"></div>");
    var table = $("<div id=\"t"+ numTables + "\"></div>");
    var tableLabel = $("<div id=\"table_label\" class=\"table_label\">" + tablename + "</div>");
    $("#table-planner-container").append(tableContainer);
    // more code that does seat appending
    }

    function Create_Guest_Element(){
    var guest = $("<span id=\"" + guestid + "\"  class=\"guest\" gender=\"" + gender + "\">"+ fname + " "+ lname +"</span>");
    $("#table-planner-container").append(guest);
    // More code that does stuff
    }

     function Create_PDF(){
     var html = $("#table-planner-container").html;
 $.ajax({
    url         : "/table_planner/CreatePdf",
    data        : {html:html},
    type        : 'POST',
    error       : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
                    console.log(xhr.status);          
                    console.log(thrownError);
     }
    });

   }
```

action.class.php:

```
  public function executeCreatePdf(sfWebRequest $request)
  {  
  $html = $_POST['html'];
  $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/pdf');
    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    return $dompdf->stream("tableplan.pdf");
   }
```

Whenever I try and post some data to this php function, it says it contains no HTML data, part of me thinks that DOMPDF doesn't like to generate from specific HTML elements pass through.

Any other alternative to this?

Comment: i use [tcpdf library](http://www.tcpdf.org) for a similar application. It can eat your cpu raw, but gets over most hurdles. Look at the `fine print`  (GNU lesser public license) to ensure your context is appropriate for use.

Comment: I would recommend you not to use the code you put in this post. Sending pure HTML via Ajax to a backend, and then putting it into a PDF, is just asking for trouble. It means that an attacker could possibly inject javascript in the PDF files your system generates.

Comment: I've used TCPDF but looks like it doesn't like to include external stylesheets and that's what is stumping me.